# Rails 4 - Passing parameter to controller method through link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have some rather ugly denormalization going on in my app, where I have 7 routes, 7 views, 7 controller methods to display the results of.....wait for it.....7 rounds in a sports draft.

I want to have a single route, view, etc...and pass a parameter into my controller method from a link.

My link looks like this:

```
 <li><%= link_to 'Round 1', round1_ownerships_path(rd_param: '1')%></li>
```

The def for round 1 looks like this:

```
def round1
foo = params[:rd_param]
@ownerships = Ownership.all.select { |m| m.round == foo}
end
```

The routes look like this (No laughing at the newbie!:)

```
resources :ownerships do
get 'last_three', on: :collection
get 'results', on: :collection
get 'round1', on: :collection
get 'round2', on: :collection
get 'round3', on: :collection
get 'round4', on: :collection
get 'round5', on: :collection
get 'round6', on: :collection
get 'round7', on: :collection

end
```

If I simply replace 'foo' with 1, it works fine. As it stands now, the round1.html.erb view loads, but there are no records. Any thoughts on how I can get this to work?

Comment: your ownership model has a round? and you are trying to get all ownerships from that round?

Comment: Or are you trying to get the results of each round for the given Ownership, since you currently have the rounds nested under the ownership?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :ownerships do
    get "rounds/:round", on: :collection,  to: "ownerships#round", as: :round
  end
```

./bin/rake routes

```
          Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                         Controller#Action
round_ownerships GET    /ownerships/rounds/:round(.:format) ownerships#round
```

then in your controller

```
def round
  @ownerships = Ownership.where(round: params[:round])
end
```

Then your `round.html.erb`  would just iterate over the results.

and you would call it like this.

```
<% 1.upto(7) do |r| %>
   <%= link_to "Round #{r}" round_ownerships_path(round: r) %>
<% end %>
```

I think that would give you what you are looking for.  if not please update the question with what is missing.

But reading the rails guides on routing should help shed some light on how to match urls to controls/params http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Doon, I'm fighting fires at the moment, I will test your response out soon. Thank you!

Comment: This worked perfectly. I simply cannot thank you enough. Not only did this work, but your answer really helped my understanding of routing. Thank you so much!