# Rails: Link to custom method with variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a simple custom method

```
def delete(foo, bar)
  @foo = Foo.find(foo)
  @bar = Bar.find(bar)
  destroy
end
```

And I want to call it from a view with the link:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', delete_articles_path(number: @number, tag: @tag), method: put, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

The route:

```
  resources :articles do 
    collection do
      put '/delete', to: "articles#delete", as: "delete_article"
    end
  end
```

I tried [like here(Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32490890/rails-4-passing-parameter-to-controller-method-through-link) But it says that we should pass data through params, while I want to pass it to the method as variables.

Comment: *I want to pass it to the method as variables* Why? You can just access through `params[:number]` and `params[:tag]`

Comment: Unfortunately, we're using this method in other places too, where arguments are being passed. I see some ways to make it through. I'm just curious if there's a smooth way to pass variables.

Comment: Then, the controller is not the right place to have such methods. Move that method to model and call it in the controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just wanted to be sure I'm not missing something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need arguments. Simply pass the variables you need via the params hash.